# SQL select each event connected to another event by person, date range only

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 database with tables that track client enrollment, service events delivered to those clients, and a single later billing event for each enrollment.

I am having trouble generating a list of billing outcomes for each service event.  Any guidance would be a godsend!

Simplified tables are:

**Enrollment:**

```
enrollment_rec_id
person_id
program_id
enrollment_start_date
enrollment_end_date
```

**Service:**

```
service_rec_id
person_id
date_of_service
program_id
```

(Note: `service_rec_id` is not referenced in any other table).

The `service.date_of_service` must be between `enrollment.enrollment_start_date` and `enrollment.enrollment_end_date`.

Every `billing` event record must be associated with at least 1 `service` record but each `service` record can be associated with many or 0 `billing` event records.)

**Billing:**

```
 billing_rec_id
 person_id
 billing date
 number_of services_billed_for
 date_of_one_of_those_services
 amount_billed
 amount_received
 enrollment_start_date
 enrollment_end_date
 enrollment_rec_id
```

(the service for `date_of_one_of_those_services` is apparently chosen randomly by the person who enters these records from among the several services included. This is the only direct reference to a `services` record. They then enter a count of services billed and the aggregate dollar amount billed and received for that person/enrollment.  ALSO, there can be multiple billing event records for the same person/enrollment.  One might show 2 services billed and another 3 services billed when an enrollment had 5 services.  ALSO there are many enrollments that have no billing event records at all, or have billing event records that list fewer services billed than service events in the enrollment date range)

Requested output includes which `service.service_rec_id` -- by person -- were billed for and a comparison of the number of `service.service_rec_id` s associated by date range/person with this `billing.billing_rec_id`. Did the number of `service.service_rec_id` in date range for each person = `billing.number_of service_billed_for`).

**Output desired is something like**

```
service.person_id, 
enrollment.program_id, 
enrollment.enrollment_start_date, 
enrollment.enrollment_end_date, 
service.service_rec_id, 
billing.billing date, 
billing.number_of services_billed_for,  
calculate_number_of_service_rec_id_for_this_billing_rec_id
```

Can anyone suggest a good strategy to pursue?

Comment: It is really to see what you have going on here. Can you create a sqlfiddle? It will help you get a decent answer.

Comment: Thank you Sean: I will try to create a sqlfiddle and post the link here!

Comment: "Every billing event record must be associated with at least 1 service record but each service record can be associated with many or 0 billing event records.)" - this would ideally be represented by a foreign key from Billing to Service, but from your column lists it's not obvious if such a key exists.  Do you mean that, ideally, in some conceptual sense, there's a 1-to-many relationship, but that's not enforced by the table structure?

Comment: Jerry: Sorry I was unclear. Yes, exactly. It is one-to-many but without a real structure, and no foreign keys from `billing`. This was an existing piece of software that someone hacked the `billing` table onto. The software maker restricts user defined fields to new user defined tables only. So they could add a `billing` table with a `billing_id`, but they couldn't add that `billing_id` to any other table or have it appear on any other front-end form.

Comment: That sure does not look 3NF to me

Comment: The enrollment dates could be gleaned from the enrollment table rather than being placed into the billing table. Is there a possibility of the billing record having different dates than the enrollment for this data? Otherwise when you join the data it would be duplicate fields and a waste of space.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. As I said below, I think Kevin's response is as close as anyone can get without creating a foreign key constraint on the `billing` table.  Again, my thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Onward into the fray, lets make some test data:

```
DECLARE @Enrollment TABLE
(   
    enrollment_rec_id INT,
    person_id INT,
    program_id INT,
    enrollment_start_date DATETIME,
    enrollment_end_date DATETIME
)

DECLARE @Service TABLE
(
    service_rec_id INT,
    person_id INT,
    date_of_service DATETIME,
    program_id INT
)

DECLARE @Billing TABLE
(
    billing_rec_id INT,
    person_id INT,
    billingdate DATETIME,
    number_of_services_billed_for INT,
    date_of_one_of_those_services DATETIME,
    amount_billed DECIMAL(19,6),
    amount_received DECIMAL(19,6),
    enrollment_start_date DATETIME,
    enrollment_end_date DATETIME,
    enrollment_rec_id INT
)

INSERT INTO @Enrollment
( enrollment_rec_id, person_id, program_id, enrollment_start_date, enrollment_end_date )
VALUES
( 1, 1, 1, '01-01-2014', '12-31-2014' ),
( 2, 1, 2, '01-01-2014', '12-31-2014' ),
( 3, 2, 3, '01-01-2014', '12-31-2014' );

INSERT INTO @Service
( service_rec_id, person_id, date_of_service, program_id )
VALUES
( 1, 1, '02-01-2014', 1 ),
( 2, 2, '03-01-2014', 1 ),
( 3, 1, '04-01-2014', 1 ),
( 4, 2, '05-01-2014', 2 ),
( 5, 1, '06-01-2014', 2 ),
( 6, 2, '06-01-2014', 2 );

INSERT INTO @Billing
( billing_rec_id, person_id, billingdate, number_of_services_billed_for, date_of_one_of_those_services, amount_billed, amount_received, enrollment_start_date, enrollment_end_date, enrollment_rec_id )
VALUES
( 1, 1, '10-01-2014', 3, '02-01-2014', 300.00, 150.00, '01-01-2014', '12-31-2014', 1),
( 2, 2, '10-01-2014', 3, '03-01-2014', 500.00, 333.00, '01-01-2014', '12-31-2014', 2);
```

Now lets join our billing and enrollment tables, when we will try to join the first service record and also get a max count of service records:

```
SELECT 
    s.person_id,
    e.program_id,
    e.enrollment_start_date,
    e.enrollment_end_date,
    s.service_rec_id,
    b.billingdate,
    b.number_of_services_billed_for,
    ns.Num_Of_Services_For_Program_Id
FROM @Billing b
INNER JOIN @Enrollment e
    ON e.enrollment_rec_id = b.enrollment_rec_id
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @Service s 
    WHERE s.program_id = e.program_id
        AND s.date_of_service BETWEEN e.enrollment_start_date AND e.enrollment_end_date
) s
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) Num_Of_Services_For_Program_Id FROM @Service s 
    WHERE s.program_id = e.program_id
        AND s.date_of_service BETWEEN e.enrollment_start_date AND e.enrollment_end_date
) ns
```

Here is the output:

```
person_id   program_id  enrollment_start_date   enrollment_end_date service_rec_id  billingdate number_of_services_billed_for   Num_Of_Services_For_Program_Id
1   1   2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 2014-12-31 00:00:00.000 1   2014-10-01 00:00:00.000 3   3
2   2   2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 2014-12-31 00:00:00.000 4   2014-10-01 00:00:00.000 3   3
```

Maybe a starting point for working on your problem?

Comment: Thank you Kevin.  This looks like what I'm trying to create in the sqlfiddle, and so helps much! The OUTER APPLY is something I'm going to have to try, as I come from PostgreSQL and haven't a lot of experience with TSQL.  I'll try it and get back here to mark this as answered or not. This may be a start of something good

Comment: @user1757478, If you like the reply and has helped you, please consider supporting the effort by accepting the answer and up voting.

Comment: Hello Kevin: Thank you, that really did get as close as I think is possible. For anyone with a similar issue, I do think this stems from a database design fault, and is essentially insoluble without creating a foreign key constraint on the `billing` table.